# c++ equivalent to python self.attribute = ObjectInstance()

Tags: python, c++, oop

i want to know if there is an equivalent way of doing this in c++:

```
class B:
    def foo(self,parameter):
        print("B method call from A, with non static method",parameter)

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()

parameter = 10
a = A()
a.b.foo(parameter)
```

Comment: What have you try for c++?

Comment: what is the purpose of the code? If you try to translate code token by token, you will end up with a mess. Already `class B:` in python has a completely different meaning than `class B` in C++. You wouldnt reimplement pythons object model in C++, but rather you would choose C++ features to implement the functionality you need. What do you need? What is the problem this code tries to solve? C++ will have different ways to solve that same problem

Comment: in other words: python can be implemented in C++, hence the answer is: yes ;)

Comment: class A containing a class B object is just `class A {public: B  b; };`. Is that what you want?

Comment: The above comments in mind... Here we go: [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d5907a25529a884). Please, keep in mind that Python is a dynamically typed language while C++ has static types. Thus, your Python sample still will work with e.g. `parameter = "Hello"`. Changing this in my C++ sample (`int parameter = "Hello";`) will result in a syntax error. To make this possible, a lot of more code would be necessary in C++... (i.e. mimicking Pythons dynamic typing with resp. C++ classes. Not that it wouldn't be possible...) ;-)

Comment: A variation: [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44d5183091103d7c) but still not dynamic typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.b` in C++ could be `this->b`, but also just `b` as `this` is implicit in C++.

However, in C++, you have to declare (member) variables, while in Python you create them by assigning to them and the type of the variable is determinated by this assignment and can be changed. So next code is similar (not compiled, tested):

```
#include <iostream>

class B { public: void foo(int x) { std::cout << x << "\n"; } };

class A { public: B b; }

int main() { A a; a.b.foo(3); }
```